# Numpy.any() between two indices of a 1D array multiple times in one step

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 1D numpy array of booleans and I need to check if there is a True element between two indices in the 1D array multiple times in one step (i.e. no looping).

An example:

```
my_data = np.array([False, True, True, False, False, False, True, False])
inds2check = np.array([[0, 3],
                       [3, 5],
                       [6, 7]])
```

And I want the following result:

```
output = np.array([True, False, True])
```

How is this possible in Python with Numpy?

Note 1: I can change the size of `inds2check` from 2D to 1D if needed.

Note 2: The ranges between the lower and upper indices are not of equal length. A 2D array of the ranges between the lower and upper indices themselves results in a numpy array of dtype object containing many numpy arrays of dtype np.int64. This type of array cannot be used to index another array. (Only a 2D array of dtype np.int can be used to index another array).

Comment: I hope this isn't homework...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think you have to iterate it, but the cost depends only on the output's size.
In your exemple, you will need iterate only 3 times.

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([False, True, True, False, False, False, True, False])
inds = np.array([[0, 3],
                 [3, 5],
                 [6, 7]])
output = [np.any(data[a:b]) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(inds)]
output = np.array(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterate it:

```
my_data = np.array([False, True, True, False, False, False, True, False])

def true_between(first, second):
    index = -1 
    if first > second:
        print("Bad indices")
    for i in range(first+1, second):
        if my_data[i]:
            print(f"YAY TRUE ITEM IN {i}")
            index = i
            return index
    print(f"NO TRUE ITEM WAS FOUND")
    return index
```

Comment: I have a lot of data to process, and iterating through it will take to long

Answer (score 0):

Create an array containing the indices of `my_data` and then use broadcasting and logic to find the elements of interest:

```
my_data = np.array([False, True, True, False, False, False, True, False])
inds2check = np.array([[0, 3],
                       [3, 5],
                       [6, 7]])
my_inds = np.array(range(0, len(my_data)))
a = my_inds[:,np.newaxis] >= inds2check[np.newaxis,:,0]
b = my_inds[:,np.newaxis] < inds2check[np.newaxis,:,1]
c = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a, b), my_data[:,np.newaxis])

np.any(c, axis=0)
```

The arrays `a`, `b` and `c` have the same number of rows as there are elements in `my_data` with a column for each range given in `inds2check`.
First we create a mask for each column to find the entries of `my_data` (`a & b`) then we find the true values (`(a & b) & c)`). Finally, we use `np.any` to find which columns contain a true value.

Comment: From my tests with this code it is very time expensive, probably because the arrays `a`, `b` and `c` are of size (num_data_points, num_inds2check) which is very large. For completeness: a simple for loop is much quicker, although I asked for no looping.

Comment: That makes sense. Broadcasting is a good trick but sometimes a loop is the best method.